# Unable to replace a substring with a new substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement in a sql wherein i need to modify a column name XYZ. In that column i want to replace every occurence of 27007 with PT. For eg : if a column value is 2700702 then the new value should be PT02. How can i acheive it ?

Comment: `replace(XYZ, '27007', 'PT')`?

Comment: Did you try `replace(XYZ,'27007','PT')`?

Comment: Thanks this helps. I was worried since 27007 can be followed by any number of characters. This would work perfect

Answer (score 0):

It you need to change the value in the table:

```
update t
    set xyz = replace(xyz, '27007', 'PT')
    where xyz like '%27007%';
```

Comment: In this case, it may be better to have no WHERE condition. Let the engine search for the string '27007' and replace it whenever it is found. With the WHERE condition, the string will be searched in every row anyway, and whenever a match is found, the REPLACE function will search for it again, multiplying the work.

Comment: Without WHERE condition, ALL rows will be updated. With WHERE condition only rows that contain `27007` will be updated.

Comment: REPLACE replaces all matches. So if you string is '27007027007', then it would be converted to 'PT0PT'. If this is not what you want, you need to use combination of substr/instr or regexp_replace

Comment: Hi vav,How can you use inst and regex to ensure that cases like '2700727007' are also handled int he expression?

Comment: @vav . . . The OP is pretty clear:  "In that column i want to replace every occurence of 27007 with PT. ".

Comment: @Kapil How do you want `27007027007` to be handled? Do you want `PT027007` as a result? If answer is no, then use Gordon solution and ignore the rest of my comment. I would not recommend regexp_replace solution because regexps are usually cryptic and harder to support (but it is fun to learn). For the simple tasks stick to the basics: `select substr('27007027007', 1, instr('27007027007', '27007')-1)||'PT'|| substr('27007027007', instr('27007027007', '27007')+5) from dual`

Comment: Here is regexp solution (for completeness): `select REGEXP_REPLACE('27007027007', '27007', 'PT', 1, 1) from dual`. The last 1 is a number of replacements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vav